# How to take screenshot of UIView and and use it has a blur background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot, blur

I have a view controller which consists of a container view which is half of the screen size over an image view, which is initially hided. the container is embedded with the tableView. i have a button which on click will display the container view and on the second click it will hide.
when that Container view is open background view should be blurred.
For that blur View i want to take screenshot of the original view place that screenshot image has background and blur that .
 I have tried this

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
 {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque,     [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];
    return img;
 }


- (IBAction)clickToBlur:(id)sender {

    [self imageWithView:_imageView];
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];


    if (!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect       effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
        UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect  ];
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        blurEffectView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
        blurEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 28, 375, 554);
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [self.view addSubview:blurEffectView];
    } else {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: Why don't u add a bigger container view and add a view above your table view and give appropriate alpha to this view so that background looks blurred.

Comment: No the container view is like drop down list it will be displayed only when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 1):

**Make custom view and then take a screen shot and fix it on that view and make your view backgroound blurr**

ScreenShot Code :

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {

     CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

     CGRect rec = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
     [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rec afterScreenUpdates:YES];

     image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return image;
 }
```

Comment: I'm able to take screenshot thing i'm struck is i was not able to blur the image and use it as background view

Comment: This method can render image with blur effect. Thanks!